# glLightfv GL_POSITION GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION glsl OpenGL3 or OpenGL4 (positional light)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

ok, I am getting lost again in a flood of tutorials which seem to mix up older GL versions with GL3 and 4. Most tutorials are using deprecated code and i'm looking for a proper OpenGL3, or maybe even better OpenGL4 replacement for this pseudo code:

```
GLfloat LightRadius=0.5f; //or whatever value.
glLightf(NumLights, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, LightRadius);
GLfloat light_position[] = { LightLoc.X,LightLoc.Y, LightLoc.Z, 1 }; //World space location
glLightfv(NumLights, GL_POSITION, light_position);
```

for phong lighting

the vs could look like this:

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 PositionNormals;

uniform mat4 projMat;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform mat4 modelMat;

out vec3 vposition;
out vec3 vnormal;

out mat4 vprojMat;
out mat4 vviewMat;
out mat4 vmodelMat;

void main(void)
{

    vprojMat    = projMat; // from what I understood I need those in the fs as well..?
    vviewMat    = viewMat;
    vmodelMat   = modelMat;

    vposition   = vec3(viewMat * modelMat * vec4 (Position, 1.0));
    vnormal     = vec3(viewMat * modelMat * vec4 (PositionNormals, 0.0));

    gl_Position     = projMat * vec4(vposition_eye, 1.0);

}
```

and the fs:

```
in vec3 vposition;
in vec3 vnormal;

in mat4 vprojMat;
in mat4 vviewMat;
in mat4 vmodelMat;

struct LightInfo                                                           
{  
    vec3 LightLocation;                                                                   
    vec3 DiffuseLightColor;
    vec3 AmbientLightColor;
    vec3 SpecularLightColor;
    float AmbientLightIntensity;
    float SpecularLightIntensity;
    float LightRadius;
};
uniform LightInfo gLight;                                         

out vec4 FragColor; 

void main (void)  
{  
    //Diffuse Lighting

    // and here I am lost. Was trying to do in eyespace, but the light seems to float more somewhere instead of having a fixed position.

    vec3 light_position = ??? gLight.LightLocation; // probably normalized?

    float dot_prod = ??? 
    dot_prod = max (dot_prod, 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse_intensity = gLight.DiffuseLightColor * dot_prod; // final diffuse intensity


    FragColor=diffuse_intensity;
}
```

the idea is rather simple, just a single light within a room shining into all directions (like a sun) with a given attenuation depending on an arbitrary radius. I just can't seem to find out the maths behind it. Forgive me if this is a silly question, but the more I read, the more I am confused. I know I need to calculate the dot for diffuse light, the facing direction of the surface (the normal) and the direction from the surface to the light, but I can't put it together.

Comment: changed GLfloat light_position[] = { LightLoc.X,LightLoc.Y, LightLoc.Z, 0 }; to GLfloat light_position[] = { LightLoc.X,LightLoc.Y, LightLoc.Z, 1 }; in my pseudo code, should have been 1 in the first place, sorry :) - other than that still trying to get through it. Either way, thanks for the first answer already

Comment: after a lot of more reading, and please forgive me if I mix up things again, I came more and more to the conclusion that my problem in a proper replacement maybe lies here (which I need later for a positional light):
normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal); - that's used in all "older" tutorials. Now I am wondering, gl_NormalMatrix should be from what i read the inverse transpose of the ModelView Matrix? but for gl_Normal I find multiple explanations which differ a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You should have all the vertex and light data in the same coordinate system. If you send light position in world coordinates, you should make the dot product with the normals in world space also. In terms of performance, it's better to send the light in eye/camera space. To achieve that you should call glLightfv like this:

```
// The 4th component of the light position should be 1, because it's a position, not a direction
GLfloat light_position[] = { LightLoc.X,LightLoc.Y, LightLoc.Z, 1 }; //World space location
// TODO: Change to eye space multiplying by the inverse of the modelView matrix
Matrix4 invModelView;
inverseOrtho(viewMatrix * modelMatrix, invModelView);
transformVector4(light_position, invModelView);
glLightfv(NumLights, GL_POSITION, light_position);    // Send light in eye space
```

If you have the lights in eye space, the pixel shader is simpler than calculating all the lighting in world space.

```
void main (void)  
{  
    //Diffuse Lighting

    vec3 light_position = gLight.LightLocation;    // Light position in eye space

    // calculate the light direction from the light to the vertex being iluminated
    float dot_prod = dot((vposition - light_position).normalize(), vnormal);
    dot_prod = max (dot_prod, 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse_intensity = gLight.DiffuseLightColor * dot_prod; // final diffuse intensity

    FragColor=diffuse_intensity;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the convention is to do lighting in eye/camera space, unless normal maps are involved in which case tangent space. That way you avoid transforming the light position for every object and specular component calculation is simpler. The only thing I can think of is for diffuse only in object space there's no need for a normal matrix multiply.

Comment: It's true, the light should be passed in eye/camera space :), I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: Or you can do neither of these and do everything in world-space like all the major deferred shading graphics engines (e.g. Unreal, CryENGINE). I personally do everything in world-space myself, because it makes a couple of post-processing filters I make heavy use of more efficient.

Comment: indeed I'd prefer to stay in world-space, this all translating seems to make a knot in my brain. I will try a bit more when I am done with my work, but could anyone provide me an example with using uniforms except glLightf? Since I'm doing this mostly for learning at the moment I try to get all the maths behind it instead of relying on fixed functions. It's being said that glLightf does some translation internally already, maybe that's causing the gap in understanding I still have, I obviously don't get what's really done there.